# Указатель на константу и константный указатель С++

Tags: c++, указатели, объявление, константа

Имеем следующее утверждение из книги Стивен Прата - Язык программирования C++ (6 издание). Стр. 330:

> Вы можете присваивать адрес как константных, так и не константных
>   данных указателю на константу, предполагая, что эти данные сами не
>   являются указателем, но присвоить адрес не константных данных
>   допускается только не константному указателю.

В моем понимании, доступны следующие вещи, что совпадает с первой частью мнения автора:

```
const int a = 5;
int b = 6;

const int * ptr = &a; //Допустимая операция, невозможно изменить значение a через указатель и переменную a.
const int * ptr2 = &b; //Допустимая операция, невозможно изменить значение b через указатель, но возможно через переменную b.
```

Однако, часть высказывания о "но присвоить адрес не константных данных допускается только не константному указателю" вызывает недопонимание, по логике автора следующее действие недопустимо:

```
int a = 5;

int * const ptr = &a; //Недопустимо, так как указатель константный, указывает на не константный тип.
```

Однако данный код успешно компилируется, что мне кажется вполне логичным, так как в результате мы получаем указатель без возможности изменения адреса, но ничего не мешает изменить значение переменной через указатель (*ptr).

Собственно вопрос, что пытается донести автор и что я неправильно понял из его высказывания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор имел в виду во второй части высказывания следующее.

Если у вас имеется следующие объявления

```
int x;
const int cx;
int *p;
```

то вы можете написать

```
p = &x;
```

но вы не можете написать

```
p = &cx;
```

Про константность самого указателя в этой цитате речь не идет. Просто имеет место неудачный перевод, что указатель на не константные данные назван неконстантным указателем.:)

Что касается вашего примера

```
int a = 5;

int * const ptr = &a;
```

то если подходить строго, то тут нет операции присвоения. Здесь имеет место инициализация константного объекта. А если вы будете использовать действительно присвоение, то компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Например,

```
int a = 5;

int * const ptr;

ptr = &a;
```

Этот фрагмент кода не будет компилироваться, так как константный указатель должен быть инициализирован при объявлении, и, более того, ему нельзя присвоить значение.

Comment: Спасибо, так и предполагал как вы написали. Все таки выходит имеется ошибка в переводе книги.

Comment: @IgrikXD Такую неточность допускают и в разговорной речи. Понимание зависит от контекста. Например, ссылки сами по себе не могут быть константными, однако везде, даже в стандарте иногда проскальзывает бытовое употребление "константная ссылка".:)

Answer (score 1):

Автор хотел сказать это:

```
const int ci = 0;
int i = 0;

const int *cptr;
int *ptr;

int main(){
    cptr = &ci;     //ok
    cptr = &i;      //ok

    ptr = &ci;      //error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'
    ptr = &i;       //ok  
}
```